# remapping bits in 8051 assembly

Tags: assembly, bit, 8051

I made a new memory module circuit that finally works for generic reading and writing to on-board memory. What I want to use is a chip that I programmed with a different programmer, but that programmer treats a different bit as the first bit on the chip. What I want to do in the most efficient way possible is to write code in 8051 that decodes the other chip.

The memory module accepts two bytes, two bits at a time in two shift registers, most significant bit first.

Every time the clock is set and reset, two bits are automatically shifted onto the chip.

Here is my code with comments illustrating the equation to use to map memory:

```
; user requests address of HighByte * 256 + LowByte

mov A,HighByte ; Access user high byte
mov C,ACC.6 ; take 6th bit (which is really bit 14)
mov HighBitAddress,C ;and set it up for shifting in high-byte register
mov A,LowByte ; Access user low byte
mov C,ACC.4 ; take 6th bit (which is really bit 4)
mov LowBitAddress,C ;and set it up for shifting in low-byte register
setb Clock
clr Clock ;at this point, High-byte register contains value of user bit 14 
          ;and Low-byte register contains value of user bit 4
```

And the process almost repeats. The only thing that changes frequently is the value of the accumulator and carry.

```
mov A,??? ;=HighByte if next bit to load is > 8 or value is LowByte
mov C,ACC.??? ; If A=HighByte, subtract 8 from wanted bit. Value can be 0 through 7.
mov HighBitAddress,C ;and set it up for shifting in high-byte register
mov A,??? ;=HighByte if next bit to load is > 8 or value is LowByte
mov C,ACC.??? ; If A=HighByte, subtract 8 from wanted bit. Value can be 0 through 7.
mov LowBitAddress,C ;and set it up for shifting in low-byte register
setb Clock
clr Clock
```

And the code repeats another 6 times.

The crazy thing with this code is that I need to use 8 lines of code just to process two bytes. I'd prefer making a defined map in code memory and accessing it, but I don't know how to access bits from it. Only whole bytes.

Any ideas without recommending crazy-long code?

**UPDATE**

Here's what I want to achieve as a solution. I want to have an array of predefined bits so that processing is simple.

For whole bytes, I can use code like the following to load in bytes one by one:

```
 mov dptr,#mydata
 byteloop:
     clr A
     movc A,@A+DPTR
     inc dptr
     ;byte is stored in accumulator for processing
 jnz byteloop
 mydata:
 db 'F','C','B','A','E','D',0h
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
 mov A,#5Ch ;our binary value in accumulator is 01011100
 mov dptr,#mydata
 byteloop:
     movcb R1,@DPTR ;get value at DPTR
     mov C,@R1 ;get bit value
     inc dptr
     ;bit is stored
 jnz byteloop
 mydata:
 db ACC.7,ACC.3,ACC.2,ACC.5,ACC.1,ACC.0,0h
```

In the above example, at the point where "bit is stored" is reached, the values to be returned for C (the carry flag) are 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, and 0 since those are the values located at the bit 7, bit 3, bit 2, bit 5, bit 1, and bit 0 of the accumulator respectively. If I want to change the order of bits received or which bits I want to receive, I can modify the DB line.

How do I achieve the above code properly with the proper commands without making my code look messy?

Comment: How about a loop? :) Not sure about your actual encoding scheme, in particular because of the misleading comment on `mov C,ACC.4 ; take 6th bit (which is really bit 4)`.

Comment: The encoding scheme is actually specific and non-sequential. If it was sequential, then I'd use a `RLC A` or a `RRC A` command.

Comment: you only have 8 possible values, perhaps a simple array {128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1}[x] could help, instead of shifting x times ?

Comment: I updated my question. Also, the shifting is used to communicate with the memory unit and to put data onto it.